# Debian 11 bullseye : how allow user to use wifi without admin password

Tags: debian, permissions, wifi, gnome

In my high school, I installed Debian 11 on some laptops (with the gnome desktop env). When my students use one of theses laptops and want to connect to wifi with their smartphones, a prompt appears and ask to submit the password administrator user. (and after the password administrator, another prompt appears and ask for the wifi password)

How can I allow my non-administrators users to connect to the wifi without need the administrator password ?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is from Debian's documentation: *Ensure your user account is a member of the netdev group*, e.g.

```
sudo useradd -G netdev jerry
```

Not sure if it applies to your setup but it's worth trying. I'd reboot just in case.